# How can I use a parameter of a struct type from a struct?

Tags: c#

I have declared a parameter of a struct type in a struct and when I try to use that parameter from the struct I get the error `NullReferencePointer`.

Also I know that you can't initialize a struct in a struct. Is there a way to use that parameter without getting that error?

I want to use the `TCommandParam` parameter from `TCommandBuffer` struct.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCommandParam
{
    public int iValue;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4096)]
    public byte[] sValue;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
    public byte[] FrameFD;       
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCommandBuffer
{
    public int Command;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public TCommandParam[] Param;
    public int ReturnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use constructor??Modify second struct as follows:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCommandBuffer
{
    public int Command;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public TCommandParam[] Param;
    public int ReturnValue;
    public TCommandBuffer(int tsize, int cmd, int ret)
    {
        Param = new TCommandParam[tsize];
        Command = cmd;
        ReturnValue = ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you do have to initialize `TCommandBuffer` somewhere right? When you initialize, then the constructor is called and the members are initialized.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it worked from the first time, it's just that I had another code uninitialized and that's why I wrote that I have the same error. Thanks for the help !!!.